# compare previous array value in v-for using the index keeps throwing undefined

Tags: arrays, angularjs, indexing, vuejs2, v-for

Only been using Vue for a couple of months and converting a angular word press to Vue: -

Im trying to compare the previous value in the array with the current on a v-for using the index. I have looked and what i was doing from every answer i can find is right but i keep getting an undefined error.

```
         <tr v-for="(score, index) in scores" :key="index">
          <td v-if="score.tied !== '=' || scores[index - 1].pos !== score.pos" :class="cell">
            {{ score.pos }}
          </td>
          ..... lots of other <td> showing more data
```

console keeps showing pos is undefined and I've seen other people have the same issue and that they used a method but have not listed how they used the method to solve the issue and one that did didn't work.

Comment: i think its trying to look in and array before the first array when i do + 1 its works fine but not displaying how i want

Answer (score 1):

fixed myself

```
             <td v-if="playerData.pos !== 'CUT'">
              <span
                v-if="
                  index !== 0 &&
                    (playerData.tied !== '=' ||
                      scores[index - 1].pos !== playerData.pos)
                "
                class="CP pos"
              >
                {{ playerData.pos }}
              </span>
              <span v-else-if="index === 0" class="CP pos">
                {{ playerData.pos }}
              </span>
              <span v-else></span>
            </td>
```